# Connection to memory (R)

Tags: r, connection

I have to repeatedly serialize (big) R objects. To avoid repeated garbage collecting of the resulting raw vectors (after profiling, it turns out that half of my script running time is spent in `gc`!) I’d like to ask R to directly write in a memory buffer -- always the same, as after each serialization I’d call a C function with `.C` that would work directly on this memory buffer; it is the result of this C function that interests me.

Is that possible? How unreasonable is it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can reduce the GC activity by setting higher init min memory size with --min-nsize and --min-vsize. But this will not solve your problem. Please check your OS for limits (Linux ulimit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might not have understood your problem,  but why don't you directly use your R object in c++ code using Rcpp.  There will be no copy and you don't not need any serialization.

Comment: At the time I asked the question, I wasn’t using Rcpp, so I wasn’t very satisfy by your answer. Now that I does use Rcpp, I see that your suggestion is the best possible. So I tag it as accepted!  

To any future reader: **LEARN RCPP!**